# Ansible custom plugin path change

Tags: ansible

Right now, by default custom plugins are stored in home directory : ~/.ansible/plugins/callback
Our custom plugins are placed in comman directory : say : /var/ansible/plugin

We dont have comman user to login to perform production activities, so if we make some changes in plugin placed in command directory, we have to ask everyone to copy it into their home directories (~/.ansible/plugins/callback)

Is there a way to avoid asking people and make it general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration option you can set in ansible.cfg or in your environment:

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-callback-plugin-path

Comment: callback_plugin="" path is defined in custom ansible.cfg. Even after that, it looks for everyone's home directory ~/.ansible/plugins/callback  and always pick the one present in home directory

Comment: Then you need to find out why you think it is set and ansible thinks it is not. I suspect ansible is not reading your ansible.cfg as you think.